# XML Parsing Error at 1:1544. Error 4: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: joomla, xml, error

I have installed Joomla 1.5.22 on a new hosting account, which doesn't have a domain yet, so it's public URL is http://cp-013.micron21.com/~annimac/

A message saying: XML Parsing Error at 1:1544. Error 4: not well-formed (invalid token).  The source code for this message is:

```
<dl id="system-message">
<dt class="error">Error</dt>
<dd class="error message fade">
    <ul>
        <li>XML Parsing Error at 1:1544. Error 4: not well-formed (invalid token)</li>

    </ul>
</dd>
</dl>
```

There is nothing in /logs to indicate what the problem is.

I have uploaded the following folders from a freshly unzipped copy of Joomla 1.5.22:

- administrator
- components
- includes
- language\en-GB
- libraries
- modules
- plugins
- templates\ja_purity
- xmlrpc

and the issue remains.  I have no custom or additional plugins, modules, or components installed.

If I change templates, the problem remains.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in your "Custom Module" go to "Module manager" find your module that should appear in that position and edit&save it, or if that's not possible copy it's content from the old (working) host and paste it into NEW "custom component" in current one.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the templateDetails.xml file in your template. Here is the tutorial how to repair it:
http://blog.jdlh.com/en/2009/02/08/joomla_xml_parsing_error/

Comment: I am not on Mac OS, I am on WinXP.

Comment: (The problem listed in your link appears specific to Mac OS.)

Comment: Try install other template to find out if your problem is in template or not. BTW, install latest version of joomla 1.5.23

Comment: Woops.  Forgot to mention that the problem remains when switching to templates.